# Dismiss keyboard for UITextField that is inside of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a UICollectionView that contains custom cells like this:

```
class DurationDayCells: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dayHourText: UITextField!
}
```

I want the UICollectionView (and its container view to move up when the keyboard pops up for the text fields) and I used `NSNotificationCenter`, `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` to do this, as in this tutorial: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-view-behind-keyboard-ios8-swift

However, the problem is that when I try to dismiss the container view (the red view, with the upside down triangle UIButton) for the UICollectionView, the keyboard stays on screen, as shown in the screenshots:

[image: one]  [image: two]

What I want to do is to hide the keyboard when I dismiss the container view, in the IBAction function associated with the UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a `self.view.endEditing(true)` after dismissing the container view.

Comment: That did it thanks a lot! Although I have a follow up question, what does `resignFirstResponder` do? I didn't really understand the documentation but a lot of tutorials seemed to  use that to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Glad it helped! The difference is that `self.view.endEditing(true)` hides every keyboard that could be in `self.view`, and `resignFirstResponder` is a method for a specific `UITextField`, so it will only hide its own keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, you must change 'view' to the 'collectionview' e.g

```
self.collectionView.endEditing(true)
```